# How to use Powermock.whenNew in Gson?

Tags: java, powermockito

I am trying to use whenNew in PoweMockito Gson, But its not working.

I used PowerMockito.whenNew to mock Gson, but no Mock is generated, and a real Gson instance is generated

Please help me with the issue, Thanks In Advance.

- test code

```java
Gson gson = PowerMockito.mock(Gson.class);
PowerMockito.when(gson.toJson(Mockito.any()).thenThow(new NullPointerException("message"));
PowerMockito.whenNew(Gson.class).whithNoArguments().thenReturn(gson);
```

```java
String json = "";
Gson gson = new Gson();

try {
    gson.toJson(object);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code of your unit test class and the result you get when you run your test method.

Comment: Thanks to your answers, I understand.